# JavaFX KeyEvent

Tags: java, javafx

I tried to get message when any key clicked but ı can't.How can I control this?

- Controller

  ```java
  import com.sun.source.tree.WhileLoopTree;
  import javafx.event.EventHandler;
  import javafx.fxml.FXML;
  import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
  import javafx.scene.control.Button;
  import javafx.scene.image.Image;
  import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
  import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
  import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
  import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
  import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
  import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
  import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;

  import java.io.File;
  import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
  import java.net.URL;
  import java.util.ResourceBundle;
  import java.util.Scanner;

  public class Sample2 implements Initializable {

      @FXML
      private AnchorPane anchor;
      @FXML
      private ImageView img1;
      @FXML
      private ImageView img2;
      @FXML
      private ImageView  img3;

      @Override
      public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {

      }

      @FXML
      public void keyPressed(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
          System.out.println("Entered...");
      }
  }
  ```
- FXML

  ```xml
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

  <?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
  <?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
  <?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

  <AnchorPane fx:id="anchor" onKeyPressed="#keyPressed" prefHeight="650.0" prefWidth="750.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Sample2">
     <children>
        <ImageView fx:id="img3" fitHeight="50.0" fitWidth="50.0" layoutX="100.0" layoutY="100.0" onKeyPressed="#keyPressed" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" style="-fx-view-order: 10;" translateZ="100.0">
           <image>
              <Image url="@../Şirine.png" />
           </image>
        </ImageView>
     </children>
  </AnchorPane>
  ```

Or is there any way to control keyevent in Javafx.
Note:I am using SceneBuilder.In SceneBuilder "On Key Presssed" ...................

Comment: Not sure what behavior you're trying to implement, but note that key events are only delivered to the focus owner (i.e. the node which has input focus).

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How can ı control this?

Comment: Actually , I trying to implement move image with arrow keys

Comment: You write that you want a message when a key is clicked, (which obviously does not work) Can you describe the outcome of you code?

Comment: I trying to check if arrow keys pressed. And move image for pressed key

Comment: key events are delivered to handlers of the focused node only: in your case, there is nothing focused, call requestFocus on either the parent or an imageView (not entirely certain, why default focus doesn't jump in ..)

Comment: How can I fix it?

Comment: By making sure the node you add the handlers to has the focus.